# Collecting the time and space results produced by `time` macro?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, gnu-common-lisp

Common Lisp provide a `time` macro for finding out how long a form takes to execute, and it prints the information to the trace output:

> [**time**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) evaluates form in the current environment (lexical and dynamic). … **time** prints various timing data and other information to trace output.
>   The nature and format of the printed information is
>   implementation-defined. Implementations are encouraged to provide such
>   information as elapsed real time, machine run time, and storage
>   management statistics.

For instance:

```
(time (length (make-array 1000000)))
      Real time: 0.0140014 sec.
      Run time: 0.0 sec.
      Space: 4000008 Bytes
      GC: 1, GC time: 0.0 sec.
```

Is there a way to collect these parameters and push them step by step into some stack or list and return it from a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things are standard: [get-internal-run-time](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get__1.htm) and [get-internal-real-time](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_in.htm):

```
(defvar *my-timings* nil)
(let ((run (get-internal-run-time))
      (real (get-internal-real-time)))
  (multiple-value-prog1 (my-code)
    (push (cons (- (get-internal-run-time) run)
                (- (get-internal-real-time) real))
          *my-timings*)))
```

Others are not (space and GC count), you need to find the [implementation-specific versions](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/debugger.html#time).

You might also consider using [`with-timing`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/tip/tree/src/cllib/log.lisp) - it provides progress reports including ETA.

Incidentally, in your code, memory allocation (`make-array`) dwarfs `length` (which is slot access for an array).

Comment: In place of my-code I called a function(if my approach is right) but its saying "variables *my-timings* has not value.

Comment: @Rorschach: you need to define the variable `*my-timings*`, e.g. `(defvar *my-timings*)`.

Comment: @Rörd : I don't know why its not working for me still.

Comment: Did you do `(defvar *my-timings* nil)`? what is your error message?

Comment: @sds : I am getting " SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable MY-TIMINGS has no value" even after setting it to nil as suggested.

Comment: please make sure that you define and use the *same* variable, i.e., both have stars around the name.